# Is there any speech dialogue on record on Palestine independence day given by the Great Britain Prime minister?

Tags: united-kingdom, political-history, palestine

Is there any speech dialogue on record on Palestine independence day on 1988 given by the United Kingdom Prime minister?

I know that Great Britain was once a proud supporter of Palestine.

Comment: From what we understand, Palestine is not independent. In 1988 Palestine Authority was given autonomy to regulate the internal affairs of Palestine.

Comment: @user571376: You've got it mixed up. In 1988 the PLO self-proclaimed a state (the procalamation was held Algiers), which was not recognized by anyone since it didn't exist in practice: the PLO was holed-up in Tunis and had no actual control of anything. The Palestinian Authority was created later, in 1993, as a result of the Oslo Accords between the PLO and Israel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a source request.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "*Palestine independence day*"you mean the [Palestinian Declaration of Independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_Declaration_of_Independence) proclaimed by Yasser Arafat on 15 November 1988, it is a relatively straightforward matter to check [Hansard](https://hansard.parliament.uk/) for any mention of `PLO`, `Palestine`, or `Palestinian` around that date.

A search from 2 November 1988 to 2 December 1988 found almost 30 references.  None of those references relate to a statement by the then Prime Minister, [Margaret Thatcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Thatcher).

---

There was a [debate](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/1988-11-30/debates/dbd85c06-5556-4e52-b87f-476dd589fe63/PalestineNationalCouncil) on the subject of the Palestine National Council's declaration in the House of Commons on 30 November 1988.  The subject of that debate was:

> To ask the Secretary of State for Foreign and Commonwealth Affairs what is the policy of Her Majesty's Government towards the Palestine National Council's recent declaration in Algiers.

As is normal on these occasions, the Prime Minister did not speak at that debate.  The Minister who spoke on behalf of the government was [Sir Geoffrey Howe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Howe), the then Secretary of State for Foreign and Commonwealth Affairs.